# Parallelize set in data.table; works with for loop;but foreach %dopar% doesn't; foreach %do% works

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, data.table, doparallel

I am trying to parallelize my code below; it works perfectly fine with foreach %do%; but not with %dopar%; could someone please help.

I did look at a few other posts and tried a few things but nothing seems to work. Is did try parLapply as well.

```
library(data.table)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
ex_dat <- expand.grid(a1 = 10:100, a2 = 500:600) %>% data.table

ex_dat[,m := list(c(1L,2L))]

for(i in 1:nrow(ex_dat)) set(ex_dat,i,3L,list(list(mean(c(ex_dat$a1[i],ex_dat$a2[i])),
                                                   sd(c(ex_dat$a1[i],ex_dat$a2[i])))))


split_ex_dat$m



ex_dat_1 <- expand.grid(a1 = 10:100, a2 = 500:600) %>% data.table

ex_dat_1[,m := list(c(1L,2L))]

split_ex_dat <- split(ex_dat_1, seq(1,nrow(ex_dat_1), length.out  = 10))


foreach(x = 1:10, .packages = c("data.table")) %do%
  {
    dt <- split_ex_dat[[x]]
    for(i in 1:919) set(dt,i,3L,list(list(mean(c(dt$a1[i],dt$a2[i])),
                                          sd(c(dt$a1[i],dt$a2[i])))))
  }

split_ex_dat$m


cl <- 30
clu <- makeCluster(cl)
registerDoParallel(clu)



ex_dat_1 <- expand.grid(a1 = 10:100, a2 = 500:600) %>% data.table

ex_dat_1[,m := list(c(1L,2L))]

split_ex_dat <- split(ex_dat_1, seq(1,nrow(ex_dat_1), length.out  = 10))


foreach(x = 1:10, .packages = c("data.table")) %dopar%
  {
    dt <- split_ex_dat[[x]]
    for(i in 1:919) set(dt,i,3L,list(list(mean(c(dt$a1[i],dt$a2[i])),
                                          sd(c(dt$a1[i],dt$a2[i])))))
  }

split_ex_dat$m

stopCluster(clu)
```

Comment: Try this: `dt <- foreach(x = 1:10, .packages = c("data.table")) %dopar%
  {
    dt <- split_ex_dat[[x]]
    for(i in 1:919) set(dt,i,3L,list(list(mean(c(dt$a1[i],dt$a2[i])),
                                          sd(c(dt$a1[i],dt$a2[i])))))
    return(dt)
  }`

Comment: Also, why do you call `split_ex_dat$m` three times in the code?

Comment: Thanks Vitali that works. And sorry having {split_ex_dat$m} in there was an error.

However I am trying ti run glms using this and a simple for loop runs much faster than {%dopar%} is there a more effecient/faster way to run it? I would think foreach should work?

Comment: scen_bin <- expand.grid(n = c(10,20,30), rate1 = c(0.1,0.2,0.3), rate2 = c(0.5,0.6,0.9))
rep <- 10000

scen_sims <- rbindlist(replicate(rep, scen_bin, simplify = F), idcol = T)
scen_sims[,glm := list(c(1L,2L))]

Comment: {jh <- foreach(x = 1:1000, .packages = c("data.table")) %dopar% 
  { 
    jh <- split_scen_sims[[x]] 
    for(i in 1:270) 
      set(jh,i,8L,list(glm(formula = c(rbinom(jh$n[i],1L,jh$rate1[i]),
                                       rbinom(jh$n[i],1L,jh$rate1[i])) ~ factor(c(rep("Trt",jh$n[i]),
                                                                                                   rep("Cont",jh$n[i]))), 
                           family = "binomial"
                           
      )))
    return(jh) 
  }}

Comment: firstly, happy that this is resolved. So, I will put this as an answer and hope you will accept it. Secondly, for optimising glm computation inside dopar, I suggest you put another question with your attempts with for loop and foreach loop asking for code o and process optimisation. Does this sound something you would agree with?

Comment: Sure, i just created another question; thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60498786/process-optimisation-of-code-within-dopar

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there but what you are actually looking for is the following code that returns the final combined value after each parallel run.

```
dt <- foreach(x = 1:10, 
.packages = c("data.table")) %dopar% {
dt <- split_ex_dat[[x]] 
for(i in 1:919) set(dt,i,3L,list(list(mean(c(dt$a1[i],dt$a2[i])), sd(c(dt$a1[i],dt$a2[i]))))) 
return(dt) }
```

Having said that, I am not sure if this is the most efficient framework for your specific problem but that is out of the scope of this question.