# Process optimisation of code within dopar

Tags: r, foreach, data.table, doparallel

I am trying to optimize my code to run glms multiple times, and I would like to leverage parallelization, either with `foreach` or some other more efficient way.

As you can see; the `for` loop takes about 800 secs to run 270000 glms; while `foreach` with `dopar` unintuitively takes for ever (It either crashes or I force it to stop after a couple of hours).

Thanks for your help.

Jinesh

```
library(data.table)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
scen_bin <- expand.grid(n = c(10, 20, 30), rate1 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3),
  rate2 = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.9))

rep <- 10000
scen_sims <- rbindlist(replicate(rep, scen_bin, simplify = FALSE),
  idcol = TRUE)
scen_sims[, `:=`(glm, list(c(1L, 2L)))]

for (i in 1:270000) {
  set(scen_sims, i, 8L, list(glm(formula = c(rbinom(scen_sims$drug[i], 1L, scen_sims$Treatment_Rates[i]),
    rbinom(scen_sims$control[i], 1L, scen_sims$Comparator_Rates[i])) ~ factor(c(rep("Trt",
    scen_sims$drug[i]), rep("Cont", scen_sims$control[i]))), family = "binomial")))
}

split_scen_sims <- split(scen_sims, seq(1, 270000, length.out = 1000))


jh <- foreach(x = 1:1000, .packages = c("data.table")) %dopar% {
  jh <- split_scen_sims[[x]]
  for (i in 1:270000) {
    set(jh, i, 8L, list(glm(formula = c(rbinom(jh$n[i], 1L, jh$rate1[i]), rbinom(jh$n[i],
      1L, jh$rate1[i])) ~ factor(c(rep("Trt", jh$n[i]), rep("Cont", jh$n[i]))),
      family = "binomial")))
  }
  return(jh)
}
```

Comment: Does the *minimal* example really need to take 800 seconds to run?

Comment: @Cole That is the closest I could get; Open to suggestions on how to optimize it though! :)

Comment: Can you make it reproducible? None of the columns used for the `glm` are present

Comment: Overwriting values in your main session from parallel sessions is often a bad idea and leads to unexpected behaviour. A better solution is to create each model in parallel, return them in a list and add that list as a new column (if wanted).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Hmm.. Thanks. I used set because I saw that it was very efficient. I am still confused as to why parallelizing with multiple cores leads to lower performance. I would really like to know, the fastest way to parallelize this code. If running 100 glms takes 6 secs, I would expect using 100 cores I should be able to run 10000 in less than 10 secs?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that using the extract function `$` within a loop makes this perform poorly. It would be better to 1) make a functions and then 2) use a regular `data.table` call.

```
fx_make_glm = function(drug, treat_rate, control, Comparator_Rates){
  glm(formula = c(rbinom(drug, 1L, treat_rate),
                  rbinom(control, 1L, Comparator_Rates)) ~
        factor(c(rep("Trt", drug), rep("Cont", control))), 
      family = "binomial")
}
```

This will greatly simplify the rest - I will use `Map` which will loop through each element of the variables of interest:

```
scen_sims[, glm := list(Map(fx_make_glm, n, rate1, n, rate2))]
```

Unfortunately, that still didn't provide as much performance as ideal :(

```
Unit: seconds
     expr  min   lq mean median   uq  max neval
  OP_loop 3.01 3.21 3.21   3.22 3.26 3.36     5
 map_call 2.64 2.89 2.90   2.92 2.96 3.08     5
```

My parallel package of choice is `future.apply` - just put `future_` in front of your `*apply` series and you have a parallel evaluation:

```
library(future.apply)
plan(multiprocess)
system.time({
  scen_sims[, glm := list(future_Map(fx_make_glm, n, rate1, n, rate2))]
})

   user  system elapsed 
   1.22    0.13    3.22 

## truncated the microbenchmark call

Unit: seconds
            expr  min   lq mean median   uq  max neval
         OP_loop 2.93 2.98 3.08   3.00 3.18 3.32     5
        map_call 2.65 2.70 2.94   2.89 3.18 3.25     5
 future_map_call 2.84 3.24 3.37   3.43 3.49 3.85     5
```

I am on Windows with 2 cores / 4 threads. If I were on Linux, I would try `plan(multicore)` to see if forking processes were more productive.

**Data generation:**

```
library(data.table)
## generate data
scen_bin <- expand.grid(n = c(10, 20, 30), rate1 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3),
                        rate2 = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.9))

rep <- 50L
scen_sims <- rbindlist(replicate(rep, scen_bin, simplify = FALSE),
                       idcol = TRUE)
scen_sims[, `:=`(glm, list(c(1L, 2L)))]
```

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks. I used set because I saw that it was very efficient.

I am still confused as to why parallelizing with multiple cores leads to lower performance.

I would really like to know, the fastest way to parallelize this code. If running 100 glms takes 6 secs, I would expect using 100 cores I should be able to run 10000 in less than 10 secs?

Comment: I am also on Windows. I feel like this would be more fruitful if I were on linux. Did you try the code at all? Regarding ```set```, you are using that part fine. It's the ```DF$var[i]``` that was killing performance. See edit - I made a better ```data.table``` method.